# How to reset the count after reading the notification

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working on notification. 
This notification will be update after inserting any data in the database. But after reading that notification the count will not reset to zero.
i.e. It will keep updating the existing data in the notification part. Like 0,1,2,...

my index.php is:

```
$msql=mysql_query("select * from messages order by emp_id desc");
        while($messagecount=mysql_fetch_array($msql))
        $id=$messagecount['emp_id`enter code here`'];
        $msgcontent=$messagecount['message'];
```

And ajax part is:

```
if(isSet($_POST['emp_id']))

{

$id=$_POST['emp_id'];

$lead_form=mysql_query("select * from comments where emp_id='$id' order by leadform_id");

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($lead_form))

{

$c_id=$r['leadform_id'];

$comment=$r['leadform_id'];
}
```

Updation code is:

```
$listsql=mysql_query("select * from comments where emp_id='$id' order by leadform_id limit $second_count,2 ");
            while($rowsmall=mysql_fetch_array($listsql))
            { 
            $c_id=$rowsmall['leadform_id'];
            $lead_date=$rowsmall['lead_date'];
            ?>

            <div class="lead_date_ui">

            <div class="lead_date_text">
            <div  class="comment_actual_text"><?php echo $lead_date; ?></div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any updating code here

Comment: Your script is probably [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com) and also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: @TimWolla.. ok will try. It means it is not possible with mysql. I need to change my database to either MySQLi or PDO.